# UIButton in custom cell not working

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, custom-cell

I have a `button` in a custom `cell`

```
class CardTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var detailsButton: UIButton!
}
```

in my `view controller` then I do this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //.....more code....
    openDealCell.detailsButton.addTarget(self, action: "push:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)      
}
```

and then:

```
func push(sender:AnyObject) {
    println("tap")
}
```

But when I clicked the `button` nothing happens.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: check detailsButton may not be linked to UITableViewCell in your interface builder. print the detailsButton in cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method and check wether object exits or not?

Comment: @Shashi3456643 when I print the button I get `<UIButton: 0x14661bce0; frame = (1 120; 348 42); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x1742375e0>>
<UIButton: 0x146534620; frame = (1 120; 348 42); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x170431160>>
`

Comment: Yea code looks fine. Can you try linking  func push(sender:AnyObject) method in interface builder and remove addTarget from cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @Shashi3456643 is it possible that the reason why is not woking is that the button is behind other views?

Comment: No Your code looks fine you have done right way. I was just telling you the other way to make this working.

Comment: Either the outlet is not connected, the execution never goes to the addTarget line or openDealCell is not the recycled object you return in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix it! The problem was not in the code but in my cell in the storyboard:

[image]

where user interaction for the cell wasn't enabled and all the other view didn't allow the user interaction.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right now I created demo project with exactly the same code as your and it works. Please check [here](https://github.com/Azat92/DemoButton) at GitHub. The issue definitely in the other stuff that you didn't show us, that code does not have any problems